# compare data with month from previous year in Qlikview

Tags: date, compare, qlikview

I'm relatively new at Qlikview and wanted to compare some data from a selected year with its previous year.

In Qlikview I have a table in which i show the count of all the contacts there have been with the customer per mount `[=count(contactsID)]` with the dimension `[contacts.month]`
I want to show an other expression with the contacts with customers in the same month a year before.
So if my table shows all the contacts from jan-2014 until dec-2014 I want a bar next to every month with the months jan-2013 until dec-2013
for example jan-2013/jan-2014; feb-2013/feb-2014; etc

some extra information:
In the database is a date saved. In Qlikview i load that as:

```
load
date as contact.date,
Year(date) as contact.year,
Month(date) as contact.month,
Day(date) as contact.day;
```

If anybody could help i would be very grateful! Thanks to all of you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer on the Qlikview community!

Add expression as:

```
count({<contact.year={$(=contact.year-1)}>}ContactID)
```

http://community.qlik.com/message/517136#517136

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem at the script side while loading data. So that you can compare year to date data with previous year with until corresponding month.

```
Transaction_Table:
 LOAD date,productID,amount
 FROM data.qvd;

concatenate

 Load AddYears(date,1) as date,productID,amount_1
 Resident data where date<=AddYears($(=max(date)),-1);
```

There will be two coloumns "amount" is current date's data and "amount_1" is previous year's same day data.